# How to manage shared preference, it take too long time to edit when shared preference have store large data?

Tags: android

Question : How to manage shared preference, it take too long time to edit when shared preference have store large data?

when i store my activity data like list data in the shared preference. when i call editor to edit some thing in the shared preferences. it takes long time to edit.

how to manage large data in the shared preferences.

Comment: Why are you storing large data in Shared preferences ?

Comment: i have application where data changes frequently and propagate to other activities. I need storage where i can easy get data and modify it frequently.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to manage a lot of data in SharedPreferences is to create a "Helper" class that contains many methods to get/set values in your SharedPreferences. For example:

```
package com.example.your_app.helpers;


import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.util.Log;

import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class AssetLoader {
    private static SharedPreferences prefs;
    private static Context context1;

    public static void load(Context context) {
        context1 = context;
        // Prefs
        prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("YourApp", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

    public static void setTotalLocations(int totalLocations) {
        prefs.edit().putInt("totalLocations", totalLocations).apply();
    }

    public static Integer getTotalLocations() {
        if(prefs != null) {
            return prefs.getInt("totalLocations", 1);
        } else {
            return -1;
        }
    }

    public static void setItemName(String id, String name) {
        prefs.edit().putString(gid, name).apply();
    }

    public static String getItemName(String id) {
        return prefs.getString(id, "");
    }
}
```

This code was just copy/pasted from one of my apps. It has a load( )method that you need to call when your app starts up which can be used to load anything necessary. Everything else can be in a getter/setter method like the examples `setItemName` and `getItemName`.

Comment: I'll test this. Thank you.

Comment: @statosdotcom You're welcome! I hope it works for you. If you need any more help, let me know!

Answer (score 0):

The way I see this. If you really need to store large data you should consider using SQLite for shared preferences recommended use (for me) should only for small values like cached app settings for example.